# HBase filter to compare two columns

Tags: hadoop, hbase, bigdata

For example, assume that each row contains three columns:

```
family1:A='10'
family1:B='45'
family1:C='35'
```

1) Is there a way to make a HBase filter which would return only rows with A>B?

2) Is there a way to make a HBase filter which would return only rows with (A-B)>C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope!  The problem is that scanners don't really get random access to qualifiers even within the same row & family.  So, if they were to try making such a filter, they'd have to skip back and forth, now reading `A`, now reading `B`, etc.

Depending on your use case, you could materialize the difference yourself in another qualifier, or perhaps use a map-reduce job.